# Sort only the keys in each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, ksort

I have an array in the following format.  How can I sort each row's data by its keys in an ascending fashion?

```
[
    [
        40 => 2,
        80 => 1,
        20 => 0,
        60 => 0,
        100 => 0,
    ],
    [
        60 => 2,
        80 => 1,
        20 => 0,
        40 => 0,
        100 => 0,
    ],
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    [
        20 => 0,
        40 => 2,
        60 => 0,
        80 => 1,
        100 => 0,
    ],
    [
        20 => 0,
        40 => 0,
        60 => 2,
        80 => 1,
        100 => 0,
    ],
]
```

I tried using `array_values()` and `array_combine()`, but with no luck.

Comment: Why use `array_combine`, which value to reserve, I see there may be same key in every item.

Comment: Do you want to combine the arrays (`0` and `1`) and then sort one final array, or sort the values inside `0` and the values inside `1`? Also, please show your PHP to show us what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_combine` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine the arrays and then use `ksort` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort the keys.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are known to the developer in advance, you can hardcode the order of the keys in a default array then overwrite the values.

`foreach()` loop modifying by reference ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gSJah))

```
$defaults = array_fill_keys(range(20, 100, 20), 0); 
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $row = array_replace($defaults, $row);
}
var_export($array);
```

`foreach()` to populate a new array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gC3ZM))

```
$defaults = array_fill_keys(range(20, 100, 20), 0);
$result = []; 
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[] = array_replace($defaults, $row);
}
var_export($result);
```

`array_map()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qqRvg))

```
$defaults = array_fill_keys(range(20, 100, 20), 0); 
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => array_replace($defaults, $row),
        $array
    )
);
```

Bear in mind that `array_merge()` does not work properly with numeric key. [Watch it not work properly](https://3v4l.org/Njtp0).

---

If the keys are not known in advance, you can use classic loops or functional iterators to sort the keys.

`foreach()` loop modifying rows by reference: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oKdPn))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    ksort($row);
}
var_export($array);
```

Note that if you don not use `&`, then the sorting will be applied to the "copy" of the array that the loop is iterating over (instead of iterating over the original array). [Watch it not work properly](https://3v4l.org/THIWM).

---

Same with `array_walk()`, you must modify by reference or the process inside of the custom function will appear to be forgotten/lost. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/n8IK5))

```
array_walk($array, fn(&$row) => ksort($row));
var_export($array);
```

---

`array_map()` can be appropriate as well and does not require modification by reference. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oUq9H))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($row) {
            ksort($row);
            return $row;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```